# Git merge conflicts- Files do not exist

Tags: git

I am attempting to merge a feature branch to the master branch. How I plan to do it is to create a branch of the current master (we can call it temp branch), and merge the release branch to the temp branch, then pull request and merge that temp branch to the master branch. So this is how I did it:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin
git checkout -b feature/temp
git pull origin release/<release-branch-name-here>
```

It is here that I get almost 1000 merge conflicts, most of them saying that the merged file does not exist on my temp branch. Any ideas on how to fix it? I don't want to go around trying to resolve 1000 or so missing files.

Comment: Consider citing a representational sample of the conflict messages. Also, you've used a rather crazy set of tags here: *where* do you plan to do this conflict resolution? (In other words: Why is this tagged with CI and github-actions if it's a merge conflict, and why is this tagged with both GitHub *and* GitLab?)

Comment: I just added all tags with git, but yeah, ill remove the github/gitlab tags

Comment: OK. Depending on the pattern of merge conflicts, you might want to specify some merge time options, and/or write a little script that uses the output from `git ls-files --stage` to resolve those things that are easily machine-resolved. But this is where the representative-sample-of-conflicts would come in.